# Java program execution

Tags: java

Please explain me how this program is behaving?

```
class A
{
    //public static String name = "asdf";

    public static final String name = "asdf";

    static {
        System.out.println("static block inside A");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("regular code block");
    }
}

public class tt 
{   
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        System.out.println(A.name);
        //A a = new A();
    }
}
```

1. While executing the above program, i got the output as  -   **asdf**
   Qns : Why none of the code blocks are not getting executed?
2. If i uncomment the non final static variable  name and 
   comment the final static variable, i got the output as  -   **static block inside A**
                                   **asdf**

   Qns : Why the regular code block is not getting executed?
3. If i comment the System.out.println(A.name); and 
   uncomment the A a = new A(); in class tt
   i got the output as                 -   **static block inside A**
                                   **regular code block**
   Qns: Here both blocks are getting executed.
       But what is the difference between static block and 
       regular block?

Comment: Did the semester just start? What's with all these bad Q's in the Java section?

Answer (score 3):

1. Because `name` is a `static final String` with a [constant expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) as its value, the body of `tt.main` is effectively compiled as

   ```
   System.out.println("asdf");
   ```

   ... there's no trace of the reference to `A.name`, so `A` doesn't get initialized.
2. The "regular" code block is an instance initializer. It's only executed when you create an *instance* of `a`.
3. Yes, at that point you're creating an instance of `A`, so both the [*static initializer*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7) and [*instance initializer*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6) are run. The static initializer will only be run once; the instance initializer will be run each time you create an instance.

Follow the links above to Java Language Specification details of each term.

Comment: Could you explain the answer for Question 1 please in detail. Still i didn't understand that part.

Comment: @sriram: Basically a static final field is initialized with a compile-time constant (including a string), any references to that field are just replaced with the value.